# Trying to install a Github package with pip

Tags: python, pip

The package I'm trying to install is at https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows

Based on some other posts, I tried running

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows.git#egg=temporal_normalizing_flows
```

which gives me the following:

```
Collecting temporal_normalizing_flows
  Cloning https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows.git to /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-install-j32p3ec2/temporal-normalizing-flows
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git clone -q https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows.git /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-install-j32p3ec2/temporal-normalizing-flows Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how else to download the package. The readme mentions opening it in a docker container, but I'm not familiar with how to do that and would rather just be able to download the thing. Here's the log:

```
2021-03-11T12:49:30,099 Using pip 20.2.4 from /Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,110 Non-user install because site-packages writeable
2021-03-11T12:49:30,135 Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5dtt1tn0
2021-03-11T12:49:30,136 Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-84yvqcne
2021-03-11T12:49:30,136 Initialized build tracking at /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-84yvqcne
2021-03-11T12:49:30,136 Created build tracker: /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-84yvqcne
2021-03-11T12:49:30,136 Entered build tracker: /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-84yvqcne
2021-03-11T12:49:30,136 Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-install-cc10euhq
2021-03-11T12:49:30,166 Collecting temporal_normalizing_flows
2021-03-11T12:49:30,166   Cloning https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows.git to /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-install-cc10euhq/temporal-normalizing-flows
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git clone -q https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows.git /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-install-cc10euhq/temporal-normalizing-flows Check the logs for full command output.
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179 Exception information:
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     status = self.run(options, args)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     return func(self, options, args)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 323, in run
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 340, in _get_abstract_dist_for
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 467, in prepare_linked_requirement
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     local_file = unpack_url(
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 239, in unpack_url
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     unpack_vcs_link(link, location)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 99, in unpack_vcs_link
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     vcs_backend.unpack(location, url=hide_url(link.url))
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 733, in unpack
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     self.obtain(location, url=url)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 641, in obtain
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     self.fetch_new(dest, url, rev_options)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/git.py", line 230, in fetch_new
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     self.run_command(make_command('clone', '-q', url, dest))
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 771, in run_command
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     return call_subprocess(cmd, cwd,
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179   File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/vcs/versioncontrol.py", line 166, in call_subprocess
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179     raise SubProcessError(exc_msg)
2021-03-11T12:49:30,179 pip._internal.exceptions.SubProcessError: Command errored out with exit status 1: git clone -q https://github.com/PhIMaL/temporal_normalizing_flows.git /private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-install-cc10euhq/temporal-normalizing-flows Check the logs for full command output.
2021-03-11T12:49:30,245 Removed build tracker: '/private/var/folders/3l/tv69nng54nsdx0t5kvn28ksh0000gn/T/pip-req-tracker-84yvqcne'
```

Comment: Append `--log log.txt` to the `pip install` command and show the log.

Comment: Good call, just did

Comment: What happens if you manually clone the repository (to anywhere available) without the `-q` flag?

Comment: I can run the pip command successfully.  What version of pip, Python, and git do you have?

Comment: welp, turns out I needed to download the Command Line Tools package. Thanks for the suggestions haha